# When using multiple resources inline, is the child resource closed when the parent is closed?

Tags: java

```
bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), 8192);
(use bis)
bis.close;
```

In this case, has the inputStream created in the connection been closed (when not autocloseable)? Is there a way I could have found this answer out myself with code?

Comment: Based on the [API]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(), if you called .read() on the InputStream, would it not return a -1 if it was closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, all stream wrappers in Java API propagate close method calls to the wrapped objects. So no, you don't have to call it on the wrapped stream - the connection input stream.